# There is already an object named 'TableName' in the database. - a different solution

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

This is not really a question (yet!) but rather sharing something that happened to me last night and the solution was completely different from those found on stackoverflow or google.

After adding some new functionality to an existing application which resulted on a couple of changes on the model I deployed the application to our development environment without an issue. However, when I deployed it to our production environment I started getting this "There is already an object named 'TableName' in the database." error.

Clearly, Entity Framework was trying to (re)create my model from scratch instead of updating it. After trying several solutions including the Global.asax SetInitializer(null), resetting migrations, etc. nothing worked and would only lead to other errors.

At some point I just rolled all of my *attempts to fix* changes back and started from scratch looking for a solution.

**The solution** was actually to go into the very first Migrations file (typically called *init* or *Initial*) and comment out the code that was trying to create the tables.
Afterwards, I could see that there was another migration trying to dropfield also generating an equally ugly error (something along the lines of "Unable to remove field 'FieldName' because it doesn't exist"), so I had to comment that line as well.

So basically, after commenting out a few migration lines, **everything started working and the model did get upgraded to the latest version**.

Now, here's the question.
Clearly, Dev and Prd were out of sync DB-wise (which is fine, to my eyes) but this ended up creating migrations that, for some reason, were not compatible with production and this is where I cannot understand how Entity Framework is not able to manage this. I mean, why was EF trying to create a table if it already existed? And why was EF trying to drop a field that was not present in the table schema?

Is this something not covered by EF? Or did something happened at some point that messed up the entire EF set up of my project?

Comment: "Dev and Prd were out of sync DB-wise (which is fine, to my eyes)" is where it occurs IMHO. They shouldn't be for EF to work properly. You should adjust your EF and migrations so that it works on both. If in your test DB there's not a table A and you set your EF to create it, it's normal that it'll fail on production where the table A already exists. Try to keep your dbs in sync. Other solution is to change your migrations so that it first checks is table A exists, but this could create problems with other auto generated scripts.

Comment: I thought EF could actually manage this itself. Why is there a _MigrationsHistory table then? I find this way of handling differences to be quite contraditory when you think that EF is there to actually abstract the developer from the database itself.

Comment: EF produces "create table A", since it's what you tell it to do. If you want it to upgrade table A, you should tell it to UpgradeToLatestVersion. But then it'll try to update an existing table A to the latest definition. If table A doesn't exist in any DB, it'll throw error again. EF can do so much, if you tell it to create a table, it'll try to create it, if you tell it to upgrade it, it'll try to upgrade it without checking for existence. There's no option like (unless you write one yourself) "update table if it exists, create if it doesn't exist". You're welcome to write your own migration.

Comment: Clear. Still, having to adjust migrations depending on the environment your are deploying to, doesn't makes sense. Again, the framework keeps track of the migrations applied to the database through the _MigrationsHistory table so, if migration A - which is creating field A1 - is not present, then it should not apply migration B1 - which is removing the same field.

Moreover, this means that if your very first migration is the "create tables" type of one, then that also means that following deployments would require you to remove this migration first to avoid errors such as this one.

Comment: Would love to hear more opinions on this.

Comment: How does your solution (removing the create code) work on new environments? How would the database get created the first time the site spins up?